Execute ServerReload method from button on Blazor .net
I am using mud blazor and net core 8. I am calling an api to consult a report, so far so good, but now I need that report
is displayed when pressing a button and I feel like this changes everything because I don't know how to execute my server reload method from a button and pass it as my parameter
TableState to configure pagination.....
When I load it at startup (without pressing any button) this works fine, but now I try to pass my function to the button and I can't find the right way to make it work the same.
My code:
My Backend component:
public partial class ProductsReport
{
  //property 1
  //property 2
  private MudTable<CustomItem> Table { get; set; }

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
     //init....
  }

  private async Task<TableData<CustomItem>> ServerReload(TableState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
      //get data from DB and configure pagination request
      var request = new CustomQuery();
      request.pageNumber = state.Page + 1;
      request.pageSize = state.PageSize;

      var resp = await QueryProducts.GetAsync(request);

      var tableData = new TableData<RoleItem>();
      if (resp)
      {
        //set Table component with pagination data from api
        tableData = new TableData<CustomItem> { TotalItems = resp.rows , Items = resp.Elements };
      }
      else
      {
        //display errors
      }
      return tableData;
  }

}

My html razor:
  <!--I need call ServerReload method from this button, bit not work becouse i need pass table state param to function backend-->
<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Size="Size.Large" OnClick="ServerReload">Create my tenant</MudButton>

<!-- 
Before: <MudTable ServerData="@(new Func<TableState, CancellationToken, Task<TableData<CustomItem>>>(ServerReload))" @ref="Table">
-->

<!--Now-->
<MudTable Elements="Table?.Items" @ref="Table" Striped="true" @ref="Table">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortLabel="Id" T="CustomItem">Identity</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortLabel="Name" T="CustomItem">Name</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortLabel="Price" T="CustomItem">Price</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Id">@context.Name</MudTd>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.IsStatic</MudTd>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Price">@context.IsDefault</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
    <PagerContent>
            <MudTablePager RowsPerPageString="rows per page" />
        </PagerContent>
</MudTable>

In summary: I need to call my ServerReload method from a button and maintain my paging logic like this
